# Spring Boot + Stomp over WS with embedded Artemis broker "Destination does not exist"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket, activemq-artemis

I have a sample that use Spring boot with Stomp over Websocket. When I change broker registration from SimpleBrokerRegistration to StompBrokerRelayRegistration, it does not work as I expected.

Here is my Websocket config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.artemis")
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
//...
 @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        // If STOMP broker not configured, create an simple fallback
        if (!StringUtil.isEmpty(host) || port > 0) {
            config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue")
                    .setRelayHost(host)
                    .setRelayPort(port);
        } else {
            config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
        }
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
@Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello")
                .withSockJS();
    }
//...
}
```

and ArtemisConfig:

```
  @Configuration
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.artemis")
    public class JmsConfig implements ArtemisConfigurationCustomizer {
        private static final String DEFAULT_TRANSPORT_PROTOCOLS = "STOMP";

        private String host;
        private int port;
        private String protocols;
    // ...
        @Override
        public void customize(org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.Configuration configuration) {
            host = StringUtil.hasText(host)?host:TransportConstants.DEFAULT_HOST;
            port = port > 0? port:TransportConstants.DEFAULT_PORT;
            protocols = StringUtil.hasText(protocols)?protocols:DEFAULT_TRANSPORT_PROTOCOLS;
            Set<TransportConfiguration> acceptors = configuration.getAcceptorConfigurations();
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(TransportConstants.HOST_PROP_NAME, host);
            params.put(TransportConstants.PORT_PROP_NAME, port);
            params.put(TransportConstants.PROTOCOLS_PROP_NAME, protocols);
            TransportConfiguration tc = new TransportConfiguration(NettyAcceptorFactory.class.getName(), params);
            acceptors.add(tc);
        }
//...
}
```

Then, I connect using javascript like that:

```
var socket = new SockJS('/hello');
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
            stompClient.connect('guest', 'guest', function(frame) {
                setConnected(true);
                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(greeting){
                    showGreeting(greeting.body);
                });
            });
```

It say can not find the queue /topic/greetings

When I use SimpMessagingTemplate like that:

```
messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", "WARN: " + warningString());
```

it throw an error:

```
StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Received ERROR {message=[AMQ339001: Destination does not exist: /topic/greetings]} session=...
```

I don't know why it did not work as SimpleBroker.

Comment: Have you configured the stomp-acceptor on your Artemis instance?

Answer (score 1):

Have you created this destination in Artemis broker.xml beforehand? Unlike ActiveMQ you have to do this, or specify automatic creation in address-seting block, like this:

```
<!--default for catch all-->
<address-setting match="#">
    <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
    <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
    <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
    <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
    <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
    <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
</address-setting>
```

In this case, any destination will be created. However, there's a catch here. When you define a queue, like this:

```
<queue name="selectorQueue">
    <entry name="/queue/selectorQueue"/>
    <selector string="color='red'"/>
    <durable>true</durable>
</queue>
```

It in fact will follow jms naming convention, and have an actual name of `jms.queue.selectorQueue`. You might try mapping to that name as well.

Comment: How can I set auto-create-jms-queues when I'm using Wildfly's built-in Artemis? There is no broker.xml in this case...

Answer (score 0):

For some reason unknown to me, Artemis (with Stomp protocol) seems to expect a topic name to start with `jms.topic.`, and a queue name with `jms.queue.`

So rename your topic to `jms.topic.greetings` and make sure you also change your StompBrokerRelay configuration to:

```
config.enableStompBrokerRelay("jms.topic", "jms.queue")
```

In this setup, the queue/topic will be created automatically when needed.

(I am using Artemis 1.3.)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for how to use Spring's `SimpMessageSendingOperations` (STOMP) with an embeedded ActiveMQ Artemis in 2021? After spending half a day, I can tell you.

Add the following dependencies (find the latest versions yourself because currently there are dependency conflicts). `reactor-netty` is currently required by spring for some reason, you may try running without it.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-jms-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-stomp-protocol</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Create the following configuration class. This is required to expose embedded artemis server to outside-vm connections. From what I understand, by default only in-VM connections are used, and I haven't found a way to utilize these with stomp relay.

```
@Configuration
public class ArenaArtemisConfiguration {

    private final ArtemisProperties artemisProperties;

    public ArenaArtemisConfiguration(ArtemisProperties artemisProperties) {
        this.artemisProperties = artemisProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public ArtemisConfigurationCustomizer customizer() {
        return configuration -> {
            try {
                configuration.addAcceptorConfiguration(
                        "netty", "tcp://" + artemisProperties.getHost() + ":" + artemisProperties.getPort()
                );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Add the following to your application.yml

```
spring.artemis:
  mode: embedded
  host: localhost
  port: 61616
```

Configure a webSocket message broker via a relay (artemis in our case)

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration {

    private final ArtemisProperties artemisProperties;

    public WebSocketConfiguration(ArtemisProperties artemisProperties) {
        this.artemisProperties = artemisProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/your-topics")
                .setRelayHost(artemisProperties.getHost())
                .setRelayPort(artemisProperties.getPort());
    }
}
```

The rest should be the same as with `enableSimpleBroker`.